# Can a Scala script reference other uncompiled scala code in the same directory?

Tags: scala, classpath

If I have two separate uncompiled scala files in the same directory as:

```
// hello.scala
object hello {
  def world() = println("hello world")
}
```

and:

```
// do.scala
hello.world()
```

I get an error when running do.scala:

```
$ scala do.scala
error: not found: value hello
```

Instead I have to compile the hello.scala file first and put it on the classpath to get it to work:

```
$ scalac hello.scala
$ scala -cp hello do.scala
hello world
```

Is there a way to get one script to call the other uncompiled scala file using the right use of import, package, classpath, the scala command line tool or something else?

Comment: I did post a similar question a while ago. The answers might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760645/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-write-a-script-which-refers-to-another-script

Answer (score 8):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but from the Scala REPL shell you can do

```
:load hello.scala
:load do.scala
```

to achieve the same result:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :load hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...
defined module hello

scala> :load do.scala
Loading do.scala...
hello world

scala>
```

If you're wanting something non-interactive for scripting

```
$ cat <<EOF | scala
:load hello.scala
:load do.scala
EOF
```

works too.

Use `:help` for more interesting things the REPL shell can do.

Comment: Interesting. If I had other jars I needed to call from the code could I use the same trick but with "cat <<EOF | scala -cp jarfile.jar"?

Comment: Doing this or just "cat myreplcommandsfile | scala" works but makes my shell unusable after that annoyingly.

Comment: I note there is another REPL trick ':cp <path>' which claims to allow you to add a jar or a directory to the classpath.  And yes I noticed it did something horrible to my xterm state after it finished too but I thought it was just me.  Not sure what the fix for that is; simply redirecting output doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into on the fly compilation/embedding the compiler. Twitter's [util-eval](https://github.com/twitter/util) is one such example.

Comment: Util-eval is [removed](https://finagle.github.io/blog/2017/04/06/announce-removals/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just put

```
:load /path/file
```

at the first line in the file you are going to load.